# Get fresh data from firestore with riverpod provider in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, riverpod

I am trying to get my provider to fetch fresh values from `firestore`.

I have a provider which is fetching values from `firestore` and provides them wihtin the app as stream.

Stream from firestore

```
Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> collectionStreamWithRadius({
required String path,
required double radius,
required String field,
required GeoFirePoint center,
  }) {
    return _streamErrorHandler(
      () {
    var reference = geoFlutterFire
        .collection(collectionRef: 
    firebaseFirestore.collection(path))
    .within(
      center: center,
      radius: radius,
      field: field,
      strictMode: true,
    );

    return reference;
  },
 );
}
```

A provider to transform the document to objects

```
@riverpod
Stream<List<Object>> objectsWithinRadius(ObjectsWithinRadiusRef 
ref) {
  final myLocation =
  ref.watch(positionStreamProvider.select((value) => 
    value.valueOrNull));
  final objectsStream = ref
  .watch(objectsWithinRadiusRepoProvider(
  myLocation!.latitude, myLocation.longitude))
  .getObjects();

  return objectsStream;
 }
```

And finally the provider I am listening to in my widget.

```
@riverpod
Option<MyObject> closeObjectLocation(CloseObjectLocationRef ref) {
    final objects = ref.watch(objectsWithinRadiusProvider
    .select((value) => value.valueOrNull));

   debugPrint("objects count: ${objects?.length}");

}
```

Logs output:

```
objects count: null
objects count: 1
objects count: 0

ref.listen(closeObjectLocationProvider, (previous, next) {
  next.fold(
    () => {},
    (object) => {
      _showCloseObjectLocationNotification(object),
    },
  );
});
```

I have been trying for days to invalidate the providers to get fresh without success.
Here the use case.
When the app starts I fetch the value from firebase and display a snackbar if some value is found. The snackbar is also shown if the value changes.
For testing I add one value such that the snackbar is shown, then I close the app and delete the value on firebase. So the collection is empty, nada, nichts, rien. Everythig is gone.
But when I open the app the debug output is as above: null for loading, 1 and then 0. The 1 causes the snackbar to be shown although there is no data left on firebase.
I have called `ref.invalidate()` everywhere I could think of without success.
I am missing something?